# Oozie spark-submit, `--driver-cores` parameter not working

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, oozie

I am doing spark submit from oozie, `--driver-cores` option is not working. For examples if i provided `--driver-cores 4`, yarn still creates 1 vCore container for driver.

Spark Opts in oozie:

```
<master>yarn-cluster</master>
<spark-opts>--queue testQueue --num-executors 4 --driver-cores 4 
                ...
            </spark-opts>
```

I have tried other config keys also like `--conf spark.driver.cores=4` and `--conf spark.yarn.am.cores=4`, even those are not working.

Any pointer will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: How are you checking the allocated vCores? Has your application been idle for some time when you checked this? Is it possible that dynamic allocation may be controlling the vcores?

Comment: @xenodevil I am checking from the resource manager console, where it shows the containers for the each application that is running

Comment: Does your application go idle? The dynamic allocation may be removing the allocated resources, right?

Comment: Dynamic allocation is not enabled in the cluster. Also driver was not idle, AFAIK dynamic allocation only applies to executors ?

Comment: Tried explicitly disabling the `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled` , no luck

Answer (score 0):

If you have specified this, your program is using 4 cores. There is no doubt in that.
You are seeing it wrong.

So in resource manager page, if you are in default settings `DefaultResourceCalculator`, it only calculates memory usage.
And for vCore usage it will always show 1, because it doesn’t calculate it.

If you can change resource manager class to `DominantResourceCalculator`, then it will show actual core usage.

Just add this properties to yarn-site.xml and **restart yarn**

```
yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DominantResourceCalculator
```

---

You can also verify this theory by going to Spark History server UI.

Before changing anything submit a spark job, find that job in spark UI.
Go to **Executors** section of that job and you will see all the executor used by spark and its **configs**.

Comment: `vCore` it is showing correctly for executors. Only for driver it is not showing cores

Comment: Anyway can you check after changing the property in yarn.

Comment: Tried it, No luck.

Comment: Can you share your yarn-site.xml, Im mainly focused on queue and application master config.